# Position button over tr/td

Tags: html, css

I need to add a close button over a `<TD>`.

The code below will position the close button correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome:

```css
.btn-edit-undo {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: -55px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #999;
}
```

```html
<td class="">
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <span>NEW</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-edit-undo" title="Edit undo">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</td>
```

The close button is correctly positioned in Firefox:

[image: Firefox example]

But not in Chrome:

[image: Chrome example]

Comment: Just add z-index to button?

Comment: Use `z-index` it should work fine, also don't use absolute positioning for your button.

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden;` from parent if you can added.

Comment: I solved with`overflow: visibile○6 on td

Answer (score 0):

try adding a z-index:

```
.btn-edit-undo{
     border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: #337AB7;
     color: #FFF;
     position: absolute;
     left: 25px;
     top:-55px;
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #999;
     z-index: 5555
}
```

Comment: the z-index you tried is greater than the z-index  of the `div`, right ?

Comment: @Webman can you post working code here, we are not able to reproduce the issue.